# How to correctly attach poetry dependencies during build?

Tags: python, monorepo, python-poetry

I have a poetry setup like the following:

```
- libs
  - notreal
    - pyproject.toml
    - notreal
      - __init__.py
      - main.py
- services
  - one
    - pyproject.toml
    - one
      - __init__.py
      - main.py
```

Within one/main.py, I am doing the following:

```
from notreal.main import main as notrealfunc

def main():
    notrealfunc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

where the pyproject.toml is

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "one"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Bob Ross <bobross@gmail.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
notreal = {path = "./notreal-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl"}

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"
notreal = {path = "../../libs/notreal"}

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I run `poetry run python service_one/main.py`, it works as expected.

The issue comes from when I build the project with `poetry build`, then try to run the installation step from the setup.py file. It does not correctly install the wheel file.

When the service build cmd creates a /dist directory, I do copy over the wheel file from the build output of the library to the /dist of the service.

The output reads as such:

```
 Invalid URL: notreal-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

I have done some research on this, where it appears that this can be resolved by changing the dependency to a dev dependency and running the package with poetry run. I do not want this though, as I plan to ship the application without poetry.

So that brings me to my question. How can I do this correctly? I am basically trying to get a mono repo working with poetry. Where the build of the repo can be packaged and used without poetry installed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Skip the usage of setup.py generated by poetry, and install the local wheel files directly. After that, it should run with `python -m one.main`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to first publish your `notreal` package to pypi registry then update the version in package `one`.

```
notreal = {path = "../../libs/notreal"}
```

giving path like this wont work when u publish it is only meant for local use.